# How to inline expand wildcard in bash?

Tags: bash

I remembered bash can do the following:

Suppose there are 3 files: a,b,c in the current directory, when I input:

```
$> somecommand *
```

and then press a key or key combinations or a key sequence, the wildcard * online expanded as:

```
$> somecommand a b c
```

but I cannot remember and cannot google out the key sequence! help!

Comment: Try `Ctrl-X` `*`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is not, you would need to bind `glob-expand-word` to a key sequence. Typically by by adding something like:

```
"\C-x*": glob-expand-word
```

to `.inputrc`.

To check current status issue something like:

```
bind -P | grep glob-expand-word
```

Where result might be:

```
glob-expand-word can be found on "\C-x*".
```

Which would mean:

<kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>

This also most likely work:

<kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-*</kbd>

---

Have a look at `bind -P` and manual(s) for other niceties.

- [Miscellaneous-Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html)
- GNU command line editing interface: [Command-Line-Editing](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html#Command-Line-Editing)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for list completion. In the man page for `bash`:

```
 COMP_TYPE
     Set to an integer value corresponding to the type of completion
     attempted  that caused a completion function to be called: TAB,
     for normal completion, ?, for listing completions after succes‐
     sive  tabs, !, for listing alternatives on partial word comple‐
     tion, @, to list completions if the word is not unmodified,  or
     %,  for  menu  completion.   This variable is available only in
     shell functions and external commands invoked by  the  program‐
     mable completion facilities
```

So it depends on the completion function for somecommand how this is completed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `set -o vi` in bash, then <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> doesn't work.

In `set -o vi` mode you need to use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> instead.

Comment: It might be worth noting that once you're in normal mode, `<C-X>*` will work, but the `<C-X>` is superfluous and does nothing. (`<C-X>` doesn't decrement as it does in vi.) If you're in insert mode, then you have to use `<Esc>` first.

Comment: This is great. What are these called? bash keyboard shortcuts? Is there some documentation where I can find more of these keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @wisbucky: A bit late, but for anyone else, GNU Readline is responsible for these. When you have a slow day, read through the EDITING COMMANDS section of `man readline`. I've been using Bash for 10 years and I'm still learning new ones.