# How to inline expand glob pattern containing character class?

Tags: bash, wildcards

I've come across this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78373/how-to-inline-expand-wildcard-in-bash) in an attempt to search for a way to inline expand my glob pattern in bash. But in my case the pattern contains some character class.

Let say I have 3 files:- `abc` `bbc` `1bc`

When I input:

```
$> somecommand [[:alpha:]]bc
```

I would like to know is there any key combination that would expand my command inline as:

```
$> somecommand abc bbc
```

I've tried `Ctrl+X` `*` key sequence with no luck. It seems it's working only for a simple glob pattern but fails to expand when a pattern contains some character class like `[[:alpha:]]`

Comment: `somecommand [a-zA-Z]bc`?

Comment: @Cyrus Assuming that they use `[[:alpha:]]` because they know it may generate different results depending on the current locale, this may not be a general solution.

Comment: I think it's down to `:` being considered as a word delimiter. See also `^X*` on `*:*`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I had not fully understood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `:` is among the list of characters that `readline` considers as word delimiters for word completion (which `bash` exposes in the `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` shell variable).

After:

```
COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS/:}
```

(to remove `:` from `$COMP_WORDBREAKS`), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> should work.

One might argue that `:` shouldn't be in that list in the first place for the very reason that it's used in character classes, but I suppose the rationale is that you want to be able to use completion on things like:

```
PATH=~/bin:/usr/locTab
```

And that mechanism is too crude (you'll notice that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> on `'a'*` doesn't work either even if you remove `'` from `$COMP_WORDBREAKS`) to accommodate both so it's a compromise. See `zsh`, a shell with much more advanced editing capabilities, that works in both cases here.